# Why is Keyboard.dismiss not working in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to make it to where when a user logs in the keyboard goes away.  I am using Keyboard.dismiss but it is not working.  The keyboard stays up on to the next page where you have to manually close it.  Does anyone know how to get the keyboard to go away?

```
onSubmitEmail() {
    this.props.dispatch(handleSubmitEmail(this.state));
    Keyboard.dismiss;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dismiss` is a function, So you need to invoke it, change `Keyboard.dismiss` to `Keyboard.dismiss();`